# Word wrapping in database or output php page?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to wrap the text within the database?
I have a address being added into the database under the address column, but whenever I try to output the database through PHP it shows that the address column is seriously long which goes all the way out of the range of the paper size.  Is there a method I could wrap these text into a specific amount of letters and have it line break on the output file or within the database?

edit: updated question with code

**CODE:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>UGGL PEUI Customer Dividend - 12-01-2014</title>
<style type="text/css">

body,td,th {
font-family: Lato, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
}
body {
    background: #C28E33;
    color: #E6FFF2;
}
table{
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table thead tr{
  font-family: Arial, monospace;
  font-size: 14px;

}

table thead tr th{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-weight:bold
}

table tr {
  font-family: arial, monospace;
  color: black;
  font-size:12px;
  background-color: white;
}

table tr.odd {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

table tr td, th{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

a:link{
  font-family:arial, monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: teal;
}

a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited{
  color:black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php

// HTML Table Output
echo 
"<table border='1'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Purchase Date</th>
<th>Mature Date</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Beneficiary First Name</th>
<th>Beneficiary Last Name</th>
<th>Beneficiary ID</th>
<th>Beneficiary Contact No.</th>
<th>Beneficiary Address</th>
<th>Bank Account Name</th>
<th>Bank Account No.</th>
<th>Bank Swift Code</th>
<th>Bank Name</th>
<th>Bank Address</th>
<th>Bank Contact No.</th>
<th>Agent Name</th>
<th>Dec. 1, 2014 (Days)</th>
<th>Dec. 1, 2014 (Dividend)</th>
</thead>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['purchase_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['mature_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['unit'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['beneficiary_first'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['beneficiary_last'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['beneficiary_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['beneficiary_no'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['beneficiary_add'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['bank_acc_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['bank_acc_no'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['bank_swift'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['bank_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['bank_add'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['bank_no'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['agent'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['first_days'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td bgcolor=#E6FFF2><b>" . $row['first_payment'] . "</b></td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

// Close MySQL
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two CSS properties:

```
<style>
.your-element{
  word-wrap:break-word;
  word-break:break-all;
}
</style>
```

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap)

References:

[Word Wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

[Word Break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)